# Как покрасить текст справа от кнопки при нажатии на нее?

Tags: javascript, html, css, веб-программирование

У меня есть следующий код:

```
<input type="button" class="btn"><p style="display: inline;">Кнопка 1</p><br>
<input type="button" class="btn"><p style="display: inline;">Кнопка 2</p><br>
<input type="button" class="btn"><p style="display: inline;">Кнопка 3</p><br>
```

Как при нажатии на одну из этих кнопок я могу покрасить текст справа от нее?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.btn').forEach(item => {
  item.addEventListener('click', event => {
      item.nextSibling.classList.add('test');
  })
})
```

```css
.test {
    background: red;
}
```

```html
<input type="button" class="btn"><p style="display: inline;">Кнопка 1</p><br>
<input type="button" class="btn"><p style="display: inline;">Кнопка 2</p><br>
<input type="button" class="btn"><p style="display: inline;">Кнопка 3</p><br>
```